Understanding Mutual Information as a Measure of Relationship: Why is Mutual Information Different for Perfectly Correlated Deterministic Functions?
Can someone explain why the mutual information (MI) between a1 and a2 is smaller than the MI between b1 and b2?
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score

a1 = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10,  8, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7])
a2 = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10,  8, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7])

b1 = np.array([0.09780311, 0.02335877, 0.10676231, 0.01144303, 0.03910861, 0.06950386, 0.06038933, 0.12563807, 0.01360671, 0.01319363])
b2 = np.log(b1)

# compute MI between a1 and a2

mi_a = mutual_info_score(a1, a2)
print(mi_a) # prints 1.609

# compute MI between b1 and b2

mi_b = mutual_info_score(b1, b2)
print(mi_b) # prints 2.303

In both cases, the second vector (a2 and b2) is a deterministic function of the first vector (a1 and b1). However, mi_a is smaller than mi_b even though a1 and a2 are perfectly correlated. Since both a2 and b2 are deterministic given a1 and b1, I would expect the mutual information values to be at least the same. Why does this discrepancy occur?

Becausemutual_info_score isn't doing what you expect, it's time to read its documentation page.

Is it better to use mutual_info_classif for the discrete a vectors and mutual_info_regression for the continuous b vectors when comparing mutual information values, or should I use mutual_info_regression for both calculations to ensure a correct comparison?

You have a more basic problem: mutual_info_score expects integer vectors for its two arguments and those integers appear to be treated as names of categories, aka "labels." Thus, your question rests on how you are using vectors to represent distributions.  Use the contingency_matrix function to see what this function is doing with your vectors.

The vectors a1 and b1 are values sampled from two different distributions; one being discrete, the other being continuous. I am not sure I fully understand why I should apply the contingency_matrix function on the vectors? However, the function contingency_matrix can't be meaningfully applied to the b vectors as their values are not discrete and doing so would return the zero matrix.

That's right.  It raises the basic question: what are you trying to do?? // The documentation for mutual_info_score explains that it computes the contingency matrix for its calculations, so computing it yourself and inspecting it will show forcibly how this function is doing something unexpected to you (thereby answering your question).

What I’m trying to do: The a vectors have a Pearson correlation of 1, showing perfect correlation. However, the b vectors don’t yield a perfect correlation, even though b2 is a deterministic function of b1, suggesting that Pearson correlation isn’t capturing their dependency. This led me to consider using mutual information as a more general measure to detect complexer dependencies. I know that I could use a rank-based approach because the deterministic function applied to the b vector is monotonic, but that’s not the point here.

You are mixing up several concepts here.  In particular, mutual_info_score does not compute the "mutual information" that is relevant to your situation.  It sounds like you ought to be asking a different question that is relevant to what you want to accomplish.

I thought that from my first comment, it was clear that I am now referring to mutual_info_regression instead. (Should I delete this question and make and post a new one instead?)

Leaving aside the problem of how mi_b and mi_a are being estimated, the ground truth values are distinct.
First we can observe that both of these transformations (identity and log) are invertible. That means,
$$I(a_1; a_2) = I(a_1; a_1)$$
$$I(b_1; b_2) = I(b_1; b_1)$$
[see wiki for data processing inequality or a textbook like Thomas & Cover for more info about this]
So the result you are showing is essentially that
$$I(a_1; a_1) \neq I(b_1; b_1)$$
Which is entirely reasonable -- the MI you compute is not saying anything about the functions but about the source variables. In this particular example, there is another twist because $a_1$ is discrete and $b_1$ is continuous.
While for discrete random variable $X$
$$I(X; X) = H(X)$$
where $H$ is Shannon entropy, this is not true for continuous variables and differential entropy $h$. In particular if $X$ is a continuous R.V., then $I(X; X)$ is infinite.
So when you estimate $I(X;X)$ from samples of a continuous variable using, say, a k-nearest neighbors estimator, you generally will get higher values the more samples you provide. You should find that if you extend b1 and b2 with more samples, you will get a higher estimate mi_b.
Hope this helps!!

thanks, very helpful and insightful. I ran simulations and can confirm that the $I(X;X)$ increases with more samples. One thing I do not understand is, why $I(X;X)$ is infinite for continuous R.V. Do you have a simple to understand explanation for this?

You need (some fraction of) one bit of information to specify each binary digit of $X$, and there's infinitely many of them -- if $X$ is continuous, then it's locally nearly uniform and so eventually each binary digit will be maximally uncertain
